# command line, how to search a pattern in the first line and delete them

Tags: linux, text

I want to delete something not useful in the first line like following:

```
1-TagDir (cs)       2-TagDir (a)      3-TagDir (cd)       4-TagDir (abc)
```

Output:

```
1       2       3       4
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
head -n 1 <file | LC_ALL=C tr -cs '[:digit:]' '[\n*]' | paste -s -
```

Comment: Yes, this works for the input and get the output.